# Install Minikube using private registry

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, minikube, docker-registry, harbor

For security purposes, I need to install [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) using private Harbor repository (it works as proxy) - `harbor.mycompany.com`.
`minikube start` has several options to use repos:

```
--registry-mirror
--mirror-repository
--insecure-registry
```

Installing without private repo works perfect. But I can't figure out how to set private Harbor repo correctly.
For example this way:

```
minikube start --registry-mirror https://harbor.mycompany.com
```

still install from public repo.
Using

```
minikube start --image-repository harbor.mycompany.com --insecure-registry harbor.mycompany.com
```

I got:

```
! The image 'harbor.mycompany.com/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.3.1' was not found; unable to add it to cache.
! The image 'harbor.mycompany.com/kube-controller-manager:v1.22.3' was not found; unable to add it to cache.
! The image 'harbor.mycompany.com/kube-proxy:v1.22.3' was not found; unable to add it to cache.
! The image 'harbor.mycompany.com/coredns/coredns:v1.8.4' was not found; unable to add it to cache
```

Looks like it creates wrong paths to images (`harbor.mycompany.com/kube-proxy:v1.22.3` instead of `harbor.mycompany.com/k8s.grc.io/kube-proxy:v1.22.3` for example)

So,
how to set private repository or mirror correctly for installing Minikube?

---

Also I tried to push all needed images to harbor.mycompany.com manually.
And use

```
minikube start --image-repository harbor.mycompany.com/minikube --insecure-registry harbor.mycompany.com:443
```

This way I don't get `! The image was not found` message, but get

```
 [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image: output: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: unauthorized to access repository
```

Even if I copy .pem file to `.minikube/certs`